# Adding moles assembly for System.Data failed

Tags: mocking, moles

I am using Microsoft Moles Framework (x86) version 0.94.51023.0 in one of the unit test projects (VS 2010 unit tests). To test the data access layer methods in the application, I tried to add moles assembly for *System.Data.dll* so that, I can mock the `SqlConnection` & `SqlCommand` objects. When I built the unit test upon adding moles assembly, the build failed with the below error details

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SqlCredential' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationIntent' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'
```

End of my output window for build displayed this :

```
error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @...\UnitTests\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args" exited with code -1002.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seem to have resolved after replacing the '*System.Data dll*' present in "***C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0***" with the version '4.0.30319.17929' found in "***C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319***". Looks like this version of dll  has the SqlCredential type defined in it and I am able to mole the System.Data dll successfully

Comment: Did you happen to have VS2012 and VS2010 installed?

Comment: Yes I do have both of them installed. Did that create this Dll mismatch ?

Comment: Yes I believe it is what caused the problem.

Comment: @ranomore .. You are right Thank you!! I have tested the same again to confirm the installation of VS 2012 to have caused the issue. Everything works just fine in the machine where only f/w 4.0 is installed. Upon installing f/w 4.5, build is breaking.

Comment: Just tried this and it worked, but I only had VS2010 installed. I'll keep you posted if it breaks other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post http://feherzsolt.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/moles-and-net-4-5/ which seems to have the right solution for fixing problems with Moles failing for generating moled assemblies for System.* dlls. When both .Net f/w 4.0 and 4.5 is installed in the same machine, for projects using 4.0 dlls, adding ReflectionOnly="true" attribute in the moles file, solves the build failure issue.